# Chaining Functions Does not Work Synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, node-postgres

I query the database as follows:

```
const testMe = async () => {
    const index = await _fetchNextIndex()

    if (index === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Next index could not fetched')
    }

    return 'Success'
}


const _fetchNextIndex = async () => {
    return db.query("SELECT nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('testme_table', 'id'))", (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error('Index could not generated')
        }
        return result.rows[0]
    })
}
```

`db` is defined as:

```
const {Pool} = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool()

module.exports = {
    query: async (text, params, callback) => {
        return await pool.query(text, params, callback)
    }
}
```

My code doesn't w work synchronously. `index` is undefined and error is thrown. However, when I debug the application I see that this line is called after a time later:

```
return result.rows[0]
```

What I miss?

**EDIT 1:** I've added `async` and `await` into `query` function.

**EDIT 2:** I've also removed the callback.

```
const {Pool} = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool()

module.exports = {
    query: async (text, params) => {
        return await pool.query(text, params)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code cannot work synchronously, db access is always asynchronous. Even if you expected it to be executed *sequentially*, your function doesn't return anything but just passes a callback to `query`. Don't use callbacks, use promises that you can `await` - `pg` even supports them natively!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the libraries you're using, but the fact that `query` takes a callback would lead me to believe it doesn't return a promise that resolves with the result.

Comment: Every `async` fnction returns a `Promise`. It is, an async object. To wait for its completion synchronously, you can use `await pool.query(...);`. `await` can only be used inside an `async` function. Anyway, `db.query` receives a callback as second parameter, so I think it won't be synchronous anyway. Check what @Bergi proposes

Comment: I've added async and await into query function but didn't work too. How can I use promises or how can I use `pg`'s native `await`? PS: I am new to NodeJS.

Comment: "*I've added async and await into query function.*" - now also remove the `callback` and you're good to go. See the examples in the pg documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Removing only callback didn't work too.

Comment: What is the difference between `query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params)` vs `query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params)`

Comment: In your `_fetchNextIndex` function, the inner, anonymous callback function returns `result.rows[0]`. I don't know if it was your intention to somehow surface that return value to the caller of `_fetchNextIndex`, but that will not happen.

Comment: I've solved my question removing callback. I also remove the async/await keywords from query function definition too. @jarmod what does `surface that return value to the caller` means?

Comment: I'm saying that `return result.rows[0]` inside of `_fetchNextIndex` doesn't do anything useful.